# Codeigniter Prevent Duplication (Uppercase and Lowercase)

Tags: php, codeigniter

`Codeigniter` Prevent Duplication (Uppercase and Lowercase)

What I want:

Prevent Duplication even for Uppercase and Lowercase in database insert

```
Example:
Apple
Banana
Cat
```

When I tried to enter a new entry

```
apple (will not work-show error) 
Bananas (works)
CAT ( will not work - show error )
```

Code that I have tried ( does not work )

```
$this->db->where('usernameDB',$usernameInput);
```

Comment: it depends on your database/schema, if it is case sensetive or not. so check it first. you can do with `$this->db->where('usernameDB like binary "Banana"', NULL, FALSE)`

Comment: Are you saying you want to insert entries like cat, Cat CAT, CAt, CaT as separate entries? And that you have this "field" set to Unique which is preventing this from happening (as it should).

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('usernameDB like binary "Banana"', NULL, FALSE)
```

This code help me solve my problem